# Scripts being stripped with jQuery .load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, load

I don't think this question has been posed before, at least not in the way I need it answered. I'm using jQuery's .load function. I have a problem when loading just page fragments.

When using something like:

```
$('#content').load('loadTest.html');
```

All of the scripts on loadTest.html load just fine. However, when loading page fragments like this:

```
$('#content').load('loadTest.html #content');
```

the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated

This is clearly documented in http://api.jquery.com/load/ which says:

**Note:** *When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is however called with a selector expression appended to the URL, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, which is why they are never executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:*

I understand that I could just externally load the script which can be used anywhere, but the thing is, I'm using a page-wide ajax system where everything is loaded dynamically. So I don't really feel like having every single javascript function that I'll ever write (100's at this point) in external files. Especially because some of these javascript functions are made from values loaded from a database which I can't account for in a .js file.

Is there any workaround for the scripts being stripped out prior to the DOM being updated? Could I in some way manually load them in? Any tiny example would be helpful to me.

Comment: For what would it be good? Or the other way round: Why don't you write your own load function that does exactly what you want?

Comment: @hakre Since the entire site is ajax driven, I don't always know what javascript functions need to be loaded when a link is clicked. I just don't know how to manually put the scripts back in that .load has stripped out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said. jQuery extracts that element before executing only that block.

You could modify the output to have the server return the data in a format you need, or just write your own. It would extract the elements you need them output them to the DOM.

Untested, but it would be along the lines of this..

```
$('#content').load('loadTest.html #content,script');
```

From memory this more valid..

```
$.get('loadTest.html',function(r){
    var els = $(r).find('#content,script');
    $('#content').html(els);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

After your comment I think you might be interested in something like [js/css lazyload](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/). It conditionally loads scripts, I'm using it on some smaller sites to load only scripts and CSS when I need them on different sub-pages or user-interaction.

You load it once in the head:

```
  <script src="js/lazyload-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then you can load scripts whenever you need them dynamically, one of the many examples:

```
// Load a single JavaScript file and execute a callback when it finishes.
LazyLoad.js('http://example.com/foo.js', function () {
  alert('foo.js has been loaded');
});
```

Works for CSS files, too.

This might be helpful in your case, however, it might change your loading logic as well. In any case I think normally you should have multiple AJAX endpoints on your server that will only return the data you ask for. Otherwise things can get specific and even tricky.

So more a comment than a real answer.